# best way to load multiple .txt files process them and display in html

Tags: javascript, html

Im new to html and js. But I heard Javascript is the best way to cover my needs. I have a huge ammount of .txt Files on a shared server space, which should be read and processed to gather the needed information. This information should be displayed in an html output. I tried to use js's fileReader but I found out that this is only usable for manually selected files. Are there any ways to get such .txt files automatically?

Comment: if they're on the server, then using pure JS you'd have to use ajax to fetch them one by one. If there are a very large number then it could be quite slow. I think you'd be better using a server-side language such as PHP or C# to read all the files and generate some HTML to display them.

Comment: The files are stored on network drives accessible via windows explorer in our companys network. Periodically some files will be added so I dont have to handle all of them at once.

Comment: if they're on a network drive then you can't access them directly via JS within a browser (due to security restrictions in browsers, designed to stop 3rd party websites from reading the contents of your drives). They need to be served over HTTP via a webserver.

Comment: TBH unless there's a concrete requirement to make this data available via a web-based interface, you'd probably be better with a desktop or console-based app of some sort.

Comment: unfortunately the usage of a web based interface is necessary. Do you think there are other ways to handle my files to use the content?

Comment: like I said, you'd be far better using a server-side language to read the files and assemble the HTML. It will be a lot more efficient than accessing them via ajax. Doing it like that also means you don't have to make the text files directly served by the webserver, all you need to expose is the script (e.g. `.php` file) which generates the HTML.